# how to print the object response in UI reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

Response from backend is something like:
​

```
dept: Object { Sales: 33, Market: 12, Finance: 22, Hr: 26 }
```

model.ts:

```
 export default interface Dept{
      categories: Record<string,number>;
    }
```

component:

```
interface State{
      dept: Array<Dept>;
    }
    class MBA extends React.Component<Props & RouteComponentProps, State> {
      state = {
        dept: []
      }
    
    componentDidMount(){
       this.service
        .getCategories()
        .then((dept) => {
          this.setState(
            {
              ...this.state,
              dept: dept,
            },
            () => {
              console.log(dept);
            }
          );
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
    render(){
    return (
    {
    this.state.dept.map((data: dept)=> {
    <div>{dept.categories}</div>
    }
    }
    )

}
service method:


  getCategories(): Promise<Array<Dept>> {
        return http
          .get("https://localhost:8080/colleges")
          .then((response) => {
            return response.data;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            throw error;
          });
      }
```

In the above code I am getting error as: this.state.dept.map is not a function. My response is of type object, but i am trying to use map.(definetely it will give an error) but not sure how to fetch object response.Can anyone please help me with it.

Comment: could you please use this: Object.keys(this.state.dept).map((keyName, i)

Comment: Other option could be to use Object.entries

Answer (score 1):

```
{Object.keys(this.state.dept).map((keyName, i) => (
    <li key={i}>
        <span>key: {i} Name: {this.state.dept[keyName].categories}</span>
    </li>
))}
```

Comment: I am getting null in the UI. I am declaring my dept as: interface State{
      dept: Array<Dept>;
    } . But dept is not an array, then how to declare my dept in my component

Comment: i can declare dept: Dept, but since i am using typescript, I am getting error in: class MBA extends React.Component<Props & RouteComponentProps, State> {
      state = {
        dept: []
      }

Comment: i can make dept of type object, but how to initialize it inside state = {   }

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like this.

Based on data, type seems like this (object with string keys and value numbers)

```
interface State {
   dept: {[key: string]: number };
}
```

default state

```
state: {
  dept: {}
}
```

render method

```
render() {
  return (
    <>
      {Object.entries(this.state.dept)?.map(([key, value]) => {
        return <div key={key}> {`${key}: ${value}`} </div>;
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```